# Answering Wo wohnst du?

Tags: english-to-german, question, idiomaticity

If the answer I want to give is

> I live near X metro station.

I would answer by saying

> Ich wohne neben dem U-Bahn Station X.

I have only learned a few accusative, dative and two-way prepositions so far.

What would be the correct way to answer this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Using dative case here is correct, as you are describing something that takes place in one location (wohnen). However, note that "U-Bahn-Station" is feminine, hence the sentence should read:

> Ich wohne neben **der** U-Bahn-Station X.

"Ausgang" (exit), for instance, is masculine. To refer specifically to the exit of the metra station, you could thus say:

> Ich wohne neben **dem** Ausgang der U-Bahn-Station X.

---

Now, "neben" actually means "next to", not "near". If you live "next to" the metro station, it means there is nothing else between, no other buildings or anything else.

In contrast, "near" just means that you live close to some place. In German, there are various ways to express that, but they are *not* two-way prepositions where you would do the dative/accusative switch. For instance, a valid way to express "near" would be "nahe", which requires a genitive:

> Ich wohne **nahe der** U-Bahn-Station X.

Comment: "nahe der" sounds pretty upscale. I'd say "in der Nähe der" in colloquial speech.

Comment: Nouns ending with *-ation* are almost always feminine btw

Comment: I think another option is *bei* (a dative preposition). My feeling is that it's closer than *in der Nähe* but not as close as *neben*. In general, there are many ways to express "near" depending on context.